# Calling a web-service from within a web-service and not waiting for the response

Tags: java, web-services, spring, rest

As part of a web-service say A, I need to call another web-service say B.

The response given to the caller of A shouldn't be dependent upon B i.e it should be returning the response back to the caller irrespective of the outcome of B, considering that B might take some time.

The systems calling A and B are both different. How do I achieve this?

Note: Using RESTful web-services/Java

Comment: Remember that, in the end, the web service operation in programming language will be a plain method for your client, so use it within an asynchronous call. Check [How to asynchronously call a method in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1842734/1065197).

Answer (score 3):

The client should invoke the *Web Service A* operation asynchronously.

*Web Service A* should invoke the *Web Service B* operation asynchronously as well.

With this, the client will always receive a response regardless of the outcome of *Web Service B*.

Most of the REST frameworks already have asynchronous invocation support:

- Once it's released, **JAX-RS 2.0** will support [asynchronous HTTP](http://java.dzone.com/articles/whats-new-jax-rs-20).
- Using **Apache CXF**: [Asynchronous Client HTTP Transport](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/asynchronous-client-http-transport.html)
- Using **Resteasy**: [Asynchronous HTTP Request Processing](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.2.1.GA/userguide/html/Asynchronous_HTTP_Request_Processing.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind 3rd party libs use jetty-client: http://www.supermind.org/blog/1023/non-blocking-nio-http-requests-in-java-with-jettys-httpclient

Here is maven package description: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-client

Answer (score 0):

As per given requirement,

Call from Client to Service A can be synchronous Restful call in your case.
Call from Service A to Service B is asynchronous.

So use restful connectivity between client to Service A as usual.

In case of Call Service A -> Service B you need to use, JMS concepts, say request and response queues. Please refer http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e15184/asynch.htm 
These are generally implemented as 2 one way requests.