# Calling async method from another method without waiting/blocking

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency

I have one webservice which is called by client.

```
public class MyWebServiceClass {
    public int myMethod() {
        myAsyncMethodInAnotherClass();
        return 2;
    }
}
```

I have another class which is acync, this class have method

```
public void myAsyncMethodInAnotherClass() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    final Receiver receiver = new Receiver(); 
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    Future future = executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Asynchronous task");
            receiver.doSomeThingElse();
        }
    }); 

    executorService.shutdown();
}
```

I want `myMethod()` inside `MyWebServiceClass` should return 2 to the client, without waiting for process inside `myAsyncMethodInAnotherClass()`. Though I have created `executorService` but it is still waiting for method to complete before returning 2.

Comment: Where have you declared it as Async?

Comment: AFAIK, this should work properly. Why do you think it waits for the method to complete?

Comment: I am not using Spring or any annotation for Async. Its simply core java

Comment: It will wait for your method to complete. Why do you think it should work asynchronously?

Comment: @Codebender I run it in debug mode and 2 is return only after  myAsyncMethodInAnotherCLass(); is executed fully.

Comment: @Naman  Then how to make it Async?

Comment: Your `myAsyncMethodInAnotherCLass()` has to complete for the execution to return back to `mywebserviceclass()`. But your `doSomeThingElse()` will happen asynchronously. Is that not happening?

Comment: @Codebender, it will not happen that way either.

Comment: @NamanGala, Why? It's spawning a new thread.

Comment: I dont want to wait for myAsyncMethodInAnotherCLass() to be completed. It should be Async.

Comment: Make your method callable and then call it.

Comment: Can you guys give example using above code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to asynchronously call a method in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842734/how-to-asynchronously-call-a-method-in-java)

Comment: @Codebender you are right. Sanjeev can you comment `receiver` line and execute your code?

Comment: Have you considered the @Asynchronous?

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html

Comment: @NamanGala I run it but its waiting inside myAsyncMethodInAnotherCLass() to be completed.

Comment: @SanjeevYadav, I ran your code (with `final Receiver receiver = new Receiver();` commented), and it is working as expected. If you want I can give you my working code.

Comment: Just a side-note: Why do you create the ThreadPool with `newFixedThreadPool(10);` All it will ever use is one Thread. With a debugger have you tried jumping into myAsyncMethodInAnotherClass to figure out at which line it is blocking? Me too, I suspect the creation of `Receiver` to block for some reason. In the code you present it is not used. Is it in the actual code?