# RecyclerView is laggy

Tags: android, picasso, android-recyclerview

I have 8 items in my RecyclerView which contains an image and a title.
The performance is extremely laggy.

I load images using Picasso. The images are not even high resolution to cause a lag.

Here is my adapter:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.CategoryViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Category> categories;

class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView categoryTitle;
    ImageView categoryImage;

    CategoryViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        categoryTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_title);
        categoryImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_thumbnail);
    }
}

public CategoryAdapter(Context context, List<Category> categories) {
    this.context = context;
    this.categories = categories;
}

@Override
public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_item, parent, false);
    return new CategoryAdapter.CategoryViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CategoryViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Category category = categories.get(position);
    holder.categoryTitle.setText(category.getCategoryTitle());
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(category.getCategoryImage())
            .into(holder.categoryImage);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return categories.size();
}
}
```

Comment: Use method tracing to determine where you are spending your time.

Comment: What makes you think it's the recycler view? Can't the laggy behaviour be associated with the fact that it might be taking loads of time to get the images? If you comment out picasso calls, is it still lagging?

Comment: The scrolling can't be lagging - Picasso is asynchronous. You're doing something wrong elsewhere

Comment: @Fred I'm not fetching images over the network. They are stored locally.

Comment: Then I guess the problem is somewhere else... Either the device is too weak or there's some other issue in the code.

Comment: Is it always laggy or only the first time you scroll down? Do you have any listeners on your recyclerView?

Comment: @ziward It is always laggy. There's no listener on it.

Comment: @Fred I've tried it on 2 different devices. Fairly new devices, so it shouldn't lag.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set any background image to your activity. if yes than check background image size.may be it is too big. that can make it laggy.

Comment: There's no background image.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to call the method Asynchronously when obtaining images from picasso. Please check the following link from more info [How to asynchronously call a method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842734/how-to-asynchronously-call-a-method-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing same issue this worked for me, after initialize recyclerview add below line

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```