# How to redirect to page first before executing a code in JSP?

Tags: jsp

After executing response.sendRedirect("uploadcomplete.jsp") in servlet doPost, it executes the java code before it shows the whole page

How do I show first the page before executing the java code?

uploadSERVLET.java

```java
public class uploadSERVLET extends HttpServlet {
  protected void doGet(...){
    response.sendRedirect("upload.html");
  }


  protected void doPost(...){
    // save uploaded file in server folder/db

    response.sendRedirect("uploadComplete.jsp");

    // do very long processing takes about 10-20~mins depending on the file uploaded
  }
```

}

Comment: Share a code snippet please.

Comment: Do you want to redirect when the process will be completed (after 10-20 min) or to redirect and don't wait the process which will run in background?

Comment: Redirect and dont wait the process

Comment: In this case you can execute the process asynchronously. Here you can see how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842734/how-to-asynchronously-call-a-method-in-java

Comment: Hi what if i only want one thread to be running on whole server for all clients? Because the processing is the same for all documents uploaded by the clients

Comment: Then it seems that you need queues or a job which will read data from db and process files sequentially.