# How to send HTTP Ok request, while method still finishes?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, http, asynchronous

I'm still new to multi-threading and I'm not sure how to implement this. I have this Spring app that I would like to be able to send from the controller *OK* status when it is called say from Postman, while the method called in it still finished in the background. Can I ask for example code how to do this? Here is the method I would like to make asynchronous:

```
public void methodForAsynchronousTask(){
    restTemplate.exchange(url, method, requestEntity, String.class);
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public ResponseEntity<?> startOutage() {
    someClass.methodForAsynchronousTask();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to asynchronously call a method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842734/how-to-asynchronously-call-a-method-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an `ExecutorService` inside your `someClass` implementation, limiting the number of threads created:

```
@Component
public class SomeClass {
  
  private ExecutorService executorService;
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;
  
  public SomeClass() {
    this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    this.restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder().build();
  }  

  public someMethodForAsynchronousTask() {
    executorService.submit( () -> {
      restTemplate.exchange(url, method, requestEntity, String.class);
      .. // and whatever else
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion @christianfoleide, it worked and is a really elegant solution