# Multiple users performing large calculation slows down the application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, concurrency, locking

I have created a web application that contains several large calculations. When a user uses the application to do these calculations, it takes less time (10-20 seconds). But when multiple users tries to do the calculations together, it takes a lot of time (10-20 minutes). When multiple users use the application for smaller tasks it works fast as expected. Problem occurs while larger calculations.

Why is this happening? Is this for processor's core/thread number? Or is this for the database keeping data locked during multiple requests?

What can be done to solve it?

Is there async await in Java like in C#, Javascript?

I have used Java, Spring, Hibernate, JPA, Tomcat, MySQL, Thymeleaf

Comment: First thing to look is the MySQL error log, locks can be viewed by a simple query second look at the query plan if all the right indexes were used. Rebuilding indexes can also help

Answer (score 1):

Based on the components you listed, your application is too complex to answer this question without more details. Use a profiler and figure out where the time is being spent.

Regarding async await, Java has extensive multithreading support via [java.lang.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) library, but only primitive instructions ([wait/yield/notify](https://www.baeldung.com/java-wait-notify)) at language level (that you most likely won't use). [How to asynchronously call a method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842734/how-to-asynchronously-call-a-method-in-java) You can use [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) to create a threadpool-backed ExecutorService and queue up tasks for it to execute.  You can use [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) to use a built-in threadpool. Or, since you use Spring, you can use Spring's [@Async](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async) annotation.

Comment: Each thread that is accessing the database needs to have its own connection.  How many connections are there?